# Update multiple key values under objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c17606f4172b33030144042"),
    "registration_attempt" : 5,
    "registration_fields" : {
        "name" : 20,
        "username" : 15,
        "password" : 0,
        "email" : 0
    },
}
```

I want to increment the counter 1 on specific fields which was requested by API.

Suppose  I would like to increment name password and email counter by 1, so I know the query by which this will be done but not working on req.body.key approach

Query is:

```
db.Collectionname.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5c17606f4172b33030144042")}, {$inc: {registration_fields.name": 1, "registration_fields.username": 1, "registration_fields.email": 1}})
```

By this query value will be updated but this things done through API by frontend that which field he wants to update.

I tried this approach:

```
let filter = {registration_fields."+req.body.name: 1, "registration_fields."+req.body.username: 1, "registration_fields."+req.body.email: 1}
db.Collectionname.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5c17606f4172b33030144042")}, {$inc: filter})
```

But this will be syntax error.

Lets say Frontend guy wants to change username and email counter then how i will do, Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Frontend guy could use string interpolation here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap dynamic keys in objects in javascript with `[]`, it isn't mongo specific.

```
const filter = {
  [`registration_fields.${req.body.name}`]: 1,
  [`registration_fields.${req.body.username}`]: 1,
  [`registration_fields.${req.body.email}`]: 1,
};
```